# Stuck on LearnStreet Ruby Training. Simple Ruby Code Lesson 5

Tags: ruby, methods

Attempting to learn Ruby using the new LearnStreet online tutorials.

Can you now write a method add_interest! on the account object, which takes one parameter percentage and adds that percentage of balance to the account?

Hint 2
Call the method with parameter 10.

Hint 1
Percentage calculation - (@balance * percentage)/100

My attempt:

```
def account.add_interest!(percentage)
  (@balance * percentage)/100
end

account.add_interest!(10)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to set `@balance`. Your method `add_interest!` only returns the value, but doesn't set the `@balance` instance variable to the new value.

```
def add_interest!(percentage)
  interest = (@balance * percentage)/100
  @balance = @balance + interest
end
```

Might work better.

Adding a bang `!` to the end of a method is a common way to communicate to other Ruby developers that the method will do something surprising like permanently mutate an object.

Comment: No, that's not what bang methods mean. A bang method means that the method does the same thing as a non-bang method, but in a more surprising manner. There should only ever be a bang method if there also is a corresponding non-bang method, and bang methods have nothing to do with mutation.

Comment: Setting @balance to (@balance * percentage)/100 doesn't really accomplish much here. That's like saying the balance is equal to the percentage of the balance which it isn't.

Comment: Ah correct, David. I was more focusing on setting the instance variable and just used the OP's original code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Ruby but just wanted to chime in. Let me know if you have any questions. And I'm 95% sure this can be refactored.

```
class Account
  def self.add_interest_to_current_balance(balance, percentage)
    percentage_amount_in_dollars = (percentage * balance)/(100)
    percentage_amount_in_dollars + balance
  end
end

puts Account.add_interest_to_current_balance(500, 10) #should return 550
```

Comment: I believe the LearnStreet app looks at the instance variable to allow the user to complete the exercise, so the method should set `@balance`.

Comment: Oh Ok I see, I've never done LearnStreet so idk. It would help if the OP would post his method containing @balance, then this would be much easier to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

100% work on learnstreet

```
def account.add_interest!(percentage)
     @balance = @balance + (@balance * percentage)/100
end

account.add_interest!(10)
```

i am stuck on it too, before :D

Answer (score 0):

This answer work for me, give it a try:

```
def add_interest!(percentage)

  interest = (@balance * percentage)/100

  @balance = @balance + interest

end

account.add_interest!(10)
```